# Configure Mocha / NodeJS within VS Code - location of test folder - test files(s) undefined

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

Mocha is installed and runs fine through Terminal, Mocha Sidebar extension added in VS Code, however when using within VS Code it doesn't appear to find any tests within either a test folder I have set up, or a test folder I navigate to within VS Code

How do you alter the Mocha settings within VS Code to point it to a different/ correct location for the /test folder?

Is it possible to run tests on a folder you navigate to within VS code explorer and how to config that?

In the Output I am currently seeing the below:

Finding tests with Mocha on Node.js at "/usr/local/bin/node"

Running Mocha with Node.js at "/usr/local/bin/node"

No Mocha options are configured. You can set it under File > Preferences > Workspace Settings.

Test file(s):
  undefined

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and a couple of things solved it:

1. `npm install -g glob`
2. `npm install -g mocha`
3. `npm install -g bluebird`
4. Add `"mocha.options": {}` to the workspace configuration.
5. Add a glob option to the workspace configuration.
6. Restart VSCode.

Apparently not having global glob, mocha, and bluebird installed will cause it to fail on this.

Comment: Thanks David, I am still struggling a little, everything is installed as suggested globally, even when I point Mocha directly to the full location of a test file that I know exists, eg {"mocha.options": 
  {"mocha.files.glob": "/home/leigh/node/leetcode/two_sum/test/test.js"}
}          I am still seeing:            Applying Mocha options:
  {
    "mocha.files.glob": "/home/leigh/node/leetcode/two_sum/test/test.js"
  }

Test file(s):
  undefined